# What is the Rout of ATmega64

Tags: microcontroller

I want to know the output impedance of the [ATmega64](http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc2490.pdf). 
Could anyone help me?
There 's nothing with this name in its datasheet.

Answer (score 4):

This graph from the ATmega64 datasheet (page 353) shows how voltage drops with output current:

[image]

That's about 200 mV per 10 mA, or an output resistance of 20 Ω. At 20 mA this increases to 25 Ω.

Comment: Tnxxxxx very much

Comment: @azin Don't forget to click on the tick mark if this answer solved your question.